# Compare two tables and reflect/synchronize changes in one of them

Tags: c#, sql-server

There is mssql table in an external customer network. The aim is to create and reflect the same table in the local server. External mssql table, of course, can be changed (data) every hour and somehow I have to check for changes and reflect that changes in local table when new rows are added/deleted or updated. Is there any efficient way to do it? Additionaly i know that this table will have thousands of records. First of all, I thought about some windows service application but have no idea what approach to do, I do not think datatable/dataset with regards to so much records is fine as i remember memory out of exception in past. Any ideas?

Comment: which sql version?

Comment: Many different ways, so far looks like a clasic [SQL replication scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Not sure what versio there is at the moment but assume not less than 2016.

Comment: Have you tried using linked servers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @WesleyNightingale But i cannot use another sql server to do that, on local server there is not sql server and cannot be, it has to be done in stand alone app.

Comment: you mean the `local server` is not a `SQL Server` ?

Comment: no, it just another server in local network where i have to develop small app to synchronize tables. There will be also another server where i will be having to synchronize data, i think it will be postgres database. So synchronization has to be done between source (sql server table) and target (postgres table) as table changes to reflect based on sql server table. So simply saying if anything happend on sql server table this change has to be reflected in postgres table to have 1:1 copy.

Comment: As a suggestion, Just have a DirtyFlag on your Sql Server Table and when even a new record inserts or updates mark the DirtyFlag as true, when you want to sync the data make use of this DirtyFlag column and insert/update the data into your destination table. For delete  you can check the primary key existence and remove if it is removed on Sql server table. Hope this helps

Comment: does anyone knows whether sqltabledependency works also with views or only with tables?

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about it is to create triggers on the existing tables that upon insert, update and delete would insert into a new sync table (or a sync table per existing table) which would mark the change pending synchronization. Your C# code would read from this table on a schedule, apply changes to the local DB and delete the rows from the 'pending' table.

For example, this is how Azure SQL Data Sync works; it creates a table per existing table in the source table and then checks all these tables. I think, depending on how many tables you have and the structure etc, you could write something like JSON in just the one table instead, and it would be easier to check one table than plenty (obviously this depends on how many actual tables we're talking about).

Comment: By the way do you know whether SqlTableDependency working also with Views? or only with tables?

Comment: No idea, sorry. What do you think about my suggestion?